# Ubuntu 15 freezes

Tags: 15.04

I have the latest version of Ubuntu 15.04 Lts, and when either I try to install a printer driver or search for a resource, the desktop freezes up. I am unable to access anything and thus have to crash out.

My computer has 32Gb of Ram and so is no slouch. Does anyone know what the problem is and how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: No we don't. Unless you provide more information. Post in a pastebin output of dmesg, of /var/lo/Xorg.log.0, of ~/xsession-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the graphic card driver. Fixed the issue by running in recovery mode and then changing the driver in Advanced Options

Answer (score 0):

I belive its due to a process called tracker

try the following in a terminal:

```
$ htop
```

then F6 to order, chose to order by CPU usage. you will instantly see the process becouse its says that its eating 100 of CPU

see the Process ID at the left (its the number)

in another terminal do:

```
$ kill process ID
```

it worked for me